# Insert JSON array to database php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

In have an array that looks like this

$content = [["4","1",1,9],["1","3",3,1],["3","4",4,7]]

I would like to insert those values into the database, this is what i've had tried

```
      if(is_array($content)) {
       foreach ($content as $c) {
         list($job_id, $job_bay_id, $row, $col) = explode(',', $c);

      try {
        update_calendar($job_id, $job_bay_id, $row, $col);

      } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = $ex->getMessage();
        $_SESSION["errorType"] = "danger";
      }
    }
  }


    function update_calendar($job_id, $job_bay_id, $row, $col){
     global $DB;

      $sql1 = "UPDATE " . TBL_CALENDAR . " SET `job_bay_id` = :job_bay_id, `tbl_row` = :row, `tbl_col` = :col WHERE `job_id` = :job_id ";
    try {
     $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql1);
     $stmt->bindValue(":job_bay_id", $job_bay_id);
     $stmt->bindValue(":row", $row);
     $stmt->bindValue(":col", $col);
     $stmt->bindValue(":job_id", $job_id);
     $stmt->execute();
     $results = $stmt->fetchAll();

      } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
     }

   }
```

Comment: Can you explain what is happening? Do you get errors, is the data not updated?

Comment: Right now it doesnt update, i dont get any errors

Comment: Have you tried some basic debugging, does it ever call `update_calendar()`, have you checked the values in each of the variables.

Comment: Yes i've debugged a litter but im not getting the values in the variables. Its like its not accepting the array

Comment: Use `print_r()` with the array to see what values are in it.